# no writting permition for quagga to write config files / CentOS 7

Tags: routing, centos7, quagga

**config:**

cat /etc/redhat-release

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

sestatus

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          disabled
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

ls -ld /etc/quagga

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 quagga quagga 70 Nov 26 15:19 /etc/quagga
```

cuagga can't write config files in /etc/quagga/

**Getting an error :**

```
Can't open configuration file /etc/quagga/zebra.conf.7ImXJy
```

Disabled selinux and made directory 777

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if quagga group exists
if so check if quagga user belongs to quagga group

Comment: yes, it seems quagga did not create the group quagga at all ... thanks